# Running a powershell script against all the computers in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

I have written a script that generates some information but I need to run it on over 160 computers in an active directory. I don't want to run this script on each machine individually, is there any way of executing this script all all the machines from one centralized location?

```
invoke-command -ComputerName test-pc -ScriptBlock {gwmi win32_service | Select-object Name, PathName | where-object {$_.PathName -notlike '"*' -and $_.PathName -like "*\* *\*"}}
```

I don't want to be logging on to each machine individually. Is there quicker way? There must be.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Sohail.

**Updated version:**

```
invoke-command -ComputerName @(Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "GBST*"} | Select-Object Name)  -ScriptBlock {gwmi win32_service | Select-object Name, PathName | where-object {$_.PathName -notlike '"*' -and $_.PathName -like "*\* *\*"}}
```

**Error message:**

```
invoke-command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects 
instead of strings.
At line:1 char:2
+     invoke-command -ComputerName @(Get-ADComputer -filter {Name -like "GBSU1*"} | S ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [Invoke-Command], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: What if you apply your command to a list of computers ? Would that fit ? Do you know how to list computers in AD ? (you can reply by editing your question and adding more information)

Comment: "apply your command to a list of computers"? Please can you elaborate? Example maybe?

Comment: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName @(Get-ADComputer * |select -expand Name) -ScriptBlock {...}`

Comment: You need to 1. list computers in AD 2. store this list in a variable 3. run your command in a foreach loop iterating over the list. I can for sure write this script in your place ... but you wouldn't learn much.

Comment: Or you can take Mathias's perfect one-liner but I advise you to try to understand the code BEFORE running it. Imagine this is malicious and deletes every found object ? ^_^

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen see my question for update of what I tried.

Comment: What does `Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like "GBST*" } | Select-Object Name` output ?

Comment: Should it not be `@(Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "GBST*"} | Select-Object -Expand Name)` Note the expand so you get a string array.

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif Notice the `-Expand` parameter with `select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your revised example where you kept the "*" in the Filter. You can't filter for all then narrow your results. Asterisk is implied when filtering based on properties.

I also added the ".Name" property to the computer search to only pass that to the invoke-command section. I tried the following code and it seemed to work.

```
invoke-command -ComputerName @((Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "GBST*"').Name) -ScriptBlock {gwmi win32_service | Select-object Name, PathName | where-object {$_.PathName -notlike 'C:\Windows\system32\*' -and $_.PathName -like 'C:\Program Files\*'}}
```

Comment: I placed your command in PS and it still gave me a few errors, but this is the script I finished with and it worked. So thumbs up for your answer:

 
invoke-command -ComputerName @((Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "GBSU*"').Name)  -ScriptBlock {gwmi win32_service | Select-object Name, PathName | where-object {$_.PathName -notlike '"*' -and $_.PathName -like "*\* *\*"}}

Comment: This is actually not a 'good' solution since Get-WmiObject supports the -computername parameter : invoke-command shouldn't be used at all in this case.

Comment: @bluuf is correct. It will probably be faster than invoke-command as well. The following should work with that model: `(Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "GBSU*"').Name | % {gwmi win32_service -ComputerName $_ | Select-object Name, PathName | where-object {$_.PathName -notlike 'C:\Windows\system32\*' -and $_.PathName -like 'C:\Program Files\*'}}`

Answer (score 3):

Just to make it shorter :

```
(Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "GBSU*"').Name | % {
    Get-WMIObject Win32_Service |
    Select-Object Name, PathName |
    Where-Object { $_.PathName -notlike '"*' -and $_.PathName -like "** **" }
}
```

As pointed out by @bluuf :

> This is actually not a 'good' solution since `Get-WmiObject` supports
>   the `ComputerName` parameter : `Invoke-Command` shouldn't be used at all
>   in this case.

Comment: This command works in respects to displaying all the services, but it does not display the results I was expecting. The 'solution' provided by @McKenning was useful in a way that it displayed service path names that contained spaces and that were not enclosed between quotations.